# Making a Saas MVC App...need customer specific views, resource files, and logic

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am building a hosted business SaaS application using MVC 4/C# 4. I'd need to have customer specific resource files, css, views, and business logic that leverage a base code layer as much as possible. How would each of these (resource files, css, views, logic) need to be structured to accomplish this?

I realize this is probably a very in depth answer...but I have no idea where to start or what to search for to begin to research this. Any pointers so I can research further?

Here are my initial thoughts on each:

**Views**

Use a Switch statement based on user to return different views.

**CSS**

Use switch statement in view to specify which css to load

**Resource Files**

I'm not using them now but need to implement, so not sure exactly how they work. From what I've seen you can specify a resource file at the class MetaData level, which is a compile time thing. Not sure how you would change this at the user level. I can see [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/181738/Creating-a-Bilingual-ASP-NET-MVC3-Application-Part), how to change it based on culture...but not by a user profile attribute (like the company they belong to).

[This](http://blogs.shaunxu.me/archive/2012/09/04/localization-in-asp.net-mvc-ndash-upgraded.aspx) looks like a start...will review more.

**Business Logic**

In my services layer, I could implement switch statements...but that seems messy. Is there a way to create a new classes that override the base classes but only for certain users? Or putting these in a separate project/dll and only using that dll reference for a certain user?

I used to work on the IBM iSeries, and they had the concept of a library path that could be set by user at login. You'd have a custom code path that overrode the base code path libraries. Is there anything similar in MVC?

**Data Localization**
In my database, I have a table for Orders and another for OrderStatuses, which may be displayed in a drop down for the user to select a status. These statuses may be 'Open' and 'Closed'. But another customer may want that in Spanish...How would you handle this?

Any other considerations I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Use switch statement

Any time someone is writing object-oriented code and mentions a switch statement to control variable requirements, alarm lights begin to flash.

When you have similar but different requirements, [polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism) is your friend.

Without knowing full details of your requirements it is difficult to provide a specific answer, but consider using the [factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) / [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) to provide objects appropriate to a specific user (or more probably, to the company associated with a specific user).

**UI Layer**

Generally speaking you could use a factory to return controller instances, based on a common subclass, that implement requirements for a specific user/customer and return views appropriate to that user.

I'm not well enough versed in the specifics of wiring routes in ASP.Net MVC to suggest how specifically to set that up, but it feels like the right approach.  Perhaps another poster can shed more light.

**Business Logic**

This is a classic use of polymorphism, when requirements vary significantly.  Alternatives to per-customer classes include configuration-driven behavior and rules engines.  The best choice depends on your specific sitation.

**Data Localization**

Things like order status in the DB should not be bound to a text like 'Open'.  They should be bound to a binary representation (e.g. an INT).  Leave it to the View to translate that meaning into something specific to the user's language.

Comment: thanks for the ideas and input. I will look into the factory pattern more. For data localization, I do not bind to text, the Statuses table has ID, DisplayText. I also have enums set up so I can set the values in code using the enum...but how do you convert a list retrieved from the DB into a localized List to populate a DDL? Can you populate the DDL with the enum itself?

Comment: You could have localization stored in a Resources file and pull in the string based on a key name. You could also store localization in the DB, depends on type of data and how it will be used.

Answer (score 2):

In a SaaS application we have developed we have clients who have their own private domains so being able to support something like that was a must. We had to be able to support:

- www.mycompany.com/u/clientname
- clientname.mycompany.com
- www.clientname.com

On of the things we considered was how we could use a single deployment/code base to handle all of these clients. What we ended up with was a Base system that could be extended through the use of "plugins" which are basically class libraries named "APP.Clients.{ClientName}".

We wrote a custom ViewEngine that allows us to make use of these plugins to load Views, Controllers and even Controller Actions from the clients custom plugin to over-ride the base site.

What we ended up with is similar to what people call "portable areas" or basically external views and controllers in an Assembly.

Clients can share a common "network" database or they can be rolled off in to their own database. Most all of the config comes from reading the current URL and having logic that can determine which "client" it is and loading their settings and processing their customization.

Being able to load the client views required adding in additional search locations for Master Pages, Views and Partial Views (why we have a custom ViewEngine).

There is no simple answer and what works for one SaaS project may not work exactly the same for another. Your architecture will likely be similar but your business needs will dictate where your project takes you!